# Test if a string contains the key of a hash in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, hashmap

I have a string and want to tell if it contains the key of a hash and if it does I would like to print the value of the hash like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my %h = ( 'key1' => 'v1', 'key2' => 'v2', 'key3' => 'v3' );
my $str = "this is a string containing key1\n";
if ($str contains a key of %h){
    print the value of that key; #i.e v1
}
```

Whats the best way to do this? (Preferably concise enough to contain in an if statement)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to search through multiple strings but have just the one unchanging hash, it might be faster to compile the hash keys into a regexp upfront, and then apply that regexp to each string.

```
my %h = ( 'key1' => 'v1', 'key2' => 'v2', 'key3' => 'v3' );
my $hash_keys = qr/${\ join('|', map quotemeta, keys %h) }/;

my @strings = (
   "this is a string containing key1\n",
   "another string containing key1\n",
   "this is a string containing key2\n",
   "but this does not\n",
);

foreach my $str (@strings) {
   print "$str\n" if $str =~ $hash_keys;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/perl -w

my %h = ( 'key1' => 'v1', 'key2' => 'v2', 'key3' => 'v3' );
my $str = "this is a string containing key1\n";
while (($key, $value) = each %h) {
  if (-1 != index($str, $key)) {
    print "$value\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I'm a bit new to perl could you explain 
"-1 != index($str, $key)"

Comment: `index` function returns `-1` when `$key` is not in `$str`, or `$key`'s position in `$str` (from `0` to just under `$str` length) if it is.

Comment: Thats a pretty unorthodox way of writing `print "$value\n" if index($str, $key)>0;`

Comment: @jaypal, `>=`, not `>`.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (big hash, keys are words and you don't want them to match sub-words) this could be the right approach:

```
my %h = ( 'key1' => 'v1', 'key2' => 'v2', 'key3' => 'v3' );
my $str = "this is a string containing key1 and key3 but notkey2, at least not alone\n";

while ($str =~ /(\w+)/g) {
    my $v = $h{$1};
    print "$v\n" if defined $v;
}
```